# Using for loop to read file line by line and match the desired key content in DOS

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, findstr

I want to read a file line by line and compare the line with user key-in data.
If the key-in data match at least 1 word of the entire line, the my dos windows will output this line.

Anyone can guide me to complete this code?

```
SET user_key_in_data=abc

FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN (%~dp0database.txt) DO (CALL :match_function)

:match_function
```

Here is my attempt code, but it does not work as what i want:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET matchpattern=NETWORK.*ISSUE

FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN (database.txt) DO (SET currentline=%%G & CALL :match_function)
pause
GOTO:eof

:match_function
    findstr /I /R /C %matchpattern% %currentline%
    if %errorlevel%==0 (
        echo %currentline%
    )
GOTO:eof
```

Updated After Stephan Reply:

Why the DOS will still print out the unnecessary output such as `FINDSTR: /C ignored` when the match condition not meet?

Below is the code + textfile + dos output?

Code:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN (log_network.txt) DO (CALL :process %%G)
pause
GOTO:eof

:process
    echo %* | findstr /I /R /C "0632" > nul
    if %errorlevel%==0 (
        echo %*
    )
GOTO:eof
```

log_network.txt file:

Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.5846"

> Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.7425" Set_Param_10A "TRUE"
>   "xnetwork.exist.1420" Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.0632"
>   Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.1112" Set_Param_10A "TRUE"
>   "xnetwork.exist.8524" Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.3675"
>   Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.3344" Set_Param_10A "TRUE"
>   "xnetwork.exist.1276" Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.4796"
>   Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.3349" Set_Param_10A "TRUE"
>   "xnetwork.exist.0048"

And the Dos output:

FINDSTR: /C ignored

FINDSTR: /C ignored

FINDSTR: /C ignored

FINDSTR: /C ignored

Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwirk.exist.0632"

FINDSTR: /C ignored

FINDSTR: /C ignored

FINDSTR: /C ignored

FINDSTR: /C ignored

FINDSTR: /C ignored

FINDSTR: /C ignored

FINDSTR: /C ignored

FINDSTR: /C ignored

Comment: This does exactly what you described: `findstr "%user_key_in_data%" "%~dp0database.txt"`

Comment: @Aacini, i just wondering will this read line by line for the entire file without using for loop? At the same time, my requirement is as long as portion of the text match, then the entire line will be printed out...that is why i choose to use for loop + findstr...

Comment: Although not explicitly documented this way, the command: `findstr "string" file` do this: 1-Read the file line by line, 2-Compare each line with the string, 3-If the string is found at any place in the line, show the line. If this is all you want to do, I don't see any reason to not just use a simple `findstr ...`

Answer (score 0):

You don`t need %currentline%. Just pass the line as a parameter to your subfunction:

```
... do call match_function %%G
```

Inside the subfunction you can use it as `%*` (all parameters)

```
:match_function
echo %* | findstr /I /R /C %"matchpattern%" >nul
if ...
```

Comment: I found that the different between `DO (SET currentline=%%G & CALL :match_function)` VS `Do call match_function %%G` is the former one will direct to output the entire line but the one suggested by you will be separated (space group) %1 %2 %3 and so on, in order to print the entire line...

So, if I use `echo %1 | findstr /I /R /C %"matchpattern%" >nul`, it only will compare the first group of sentence to the match pattern.. everything after the space character will be ignored...

Comment: easy to solve: use `%*`. Sorry, I should have thought of that.

Comment: I think it will not work until we add the `"token=*"`

Hmmm, @Stephan, Can you help to take a look at question posted in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136579/what-is-the-differences-between-2-findstr-code-below) ?

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "matchpattern=NETWORK.*ISSUE"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q24133524.txt) DO (SET currentline=%%a & CALL :match_function)
ECHO(=============
FINDSTR /i /r /c:"%matchpattern%" q24133524.txt


GOTO :EOF
:match_function
    ECHO(%currentline%|findstr /I /R /C:"%matchpattern%"
    if %errorlevel%==0 (
        echo %currentline%
    )
GOTO :eof
```

I used a file named `q24133524.txt` containing your data for my testing.

This shows the results from a odified version of your procedure (the `findstr` finds the string and outputs it, then the `if errorlevel...` outputs it again.

The second way is far easier...

Comment: there will be multiple "NETWORK ISSUE DETECTED" line appear as output if using your code...Even I remove the `ECHO(=============
FINDSTR /i /r /c:"%matchpattern%" q24133524.txt` line, it will still have 2 line of "NETWORK ISSUE DETECTED" line appear but there is only 1 "NETWORK ISSUE DETECTED" line in the tet file...

Comment: the latest code that I added in the bottom of your post will achieve what my objective...Thanks...