# what is the differences between 2 findstr code below?

Tags: batch-file, findstr

May I know what is the differences between 2 findstr code below?

First Case:

```
findstr /m 0632 log_network.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
    echo FOUND
) else (
    echo NOT FOUND
)
```

Second Case:

```
set entire_line="0632"
echo %entire_line% | findstr /m log_network.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
    echo FOUND
) else (
    echo NOT FOUND
)
```

The first case return "FOUND" and the second case return "NOT FOUND"...
Also, i always see people like to use:

```
echo %something% | findstr /m filename.txt > null
```

But I don't understand why they write in this way...

log_network.txt Content:

```
Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.5846"
Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.7425"
Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.1420"
Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.0632"
Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.1112"
Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.8524"
Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.3675"
Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.3344"
Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.1276"
Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.4796"
Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.3349"
Set_Param_10A "TRUE" "xnetwork.exist.0048"
```

Thanks...

Comment: Humm... I do NOT like to use `echo %something% | findstr "search"`. This is usually done _with every line of a file_ that imply to execute findstr.exe (a 30KB size file) several times (it is s_l_o_w...). This test may usually be achieved with a simple `if` that is a lot faster!

Answer (score 0):

First case is searching the string `0632` into the file `log_network.txt` and if it is found in the file, the name of the file will be echoed to console (`/m` switch). If found, errorlevel will be 0, if not found, errorlevel will be 1.

Second case is searching the string `log_network.txt` in the data it receives from stdin, that is, `"0632"`. This is probably an error or a misinterpretation on the way findstr works.

To "mimic" the functionality of the first code, but using the structure of the second, it should be something like

```
set "entire_line=0632"
echo %entire_line%| findstr /g:/ /m log_network.txt
```

That is, first remove the quotes from the searched value (in the original code they are included in the value), and then ask findstr to take search strings from stdin (`/g:/`), check them against the content of the file `log_network.txt` and output the name of the file if any coincidence is found (`/m`)

In any case, it is a lot more efficient the first construct. Creating a pipe involves more cpu usage than just leaving `findstr` directly do the work.